# Difference between NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear & NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uilocalnotification, nscalendar

I want to make a `UILocalNotification` repeat every week, before iOS7 I would use `localNotification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit` - except `NSWeekCalendarUnit` has been deprecated.

The docs say:

> "Use NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth or NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear, depending
>   on which you mean"

But I don't know what the difference is, so I don't know which one I mean.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These don't appear to be documented but most likely `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear` will be a value from 1-53 (or maybe 0-52) representing the week number within the calendar year while `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth` will be 1-5 (or maybe 0-4) representing the week within the month.

This all assumes Gregorian calendar. I can't speak to other calendar types.

It seems that `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth` is equal to `kCFCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth` which is defined as "Specifies the original week of a month calendar unit." and `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear` is equal to `kCFCalendarUnitWeekOfYear` which is defined as "Specifies the original week of the year calendar unit.".

Comment: But which actually just means a week? Both? Or do I just hack a 7 * NSDayCalendarUnit ?

Comment: What data are you trying to get? In other words, how are you trying to use one of these values?

Comment: I'm trying to get the UILocalNotification to repeat every week.

Comment: It would be best to update your question showing what you are trying to do. Include your relevant code showing where you need to make use of one of these constants. It's hard to help with no context.

Comment: Assuming you want to repeat every week of the year, I would try `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear`.

Comment: But how does that differ from `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth` - will it still repeat every week of the year?

Comment: I honestly don't know how these values apply to setting up a local notification. My answer applied to your original question, before you mentioned it was for `UILocalNotification`. Apple's docs appear to need to be updated in this regard.

Comment: OK thanks - I guess I just need to wait a week and a month and year to fully debug the notification ;)

Comment: Wouldn't the usage of these two vary on the ordinality?

Answer (score 26):

As for the `UILocalNotification`

`NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear` should be used as a unit for `repeatInterval`.

When I set `repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth` for the notification scheduled 10 seconds from now, the notification doesn't fire, and the description of the instance of `UILocalNotification` prints `.. next fire date = (null) ...`

If I use `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear` then notification appears and I see correct next fire date from code in the notification's description.

Comment: Odd, `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth` worked for me for some time, but then at some point it got broken. `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear` fixed the bug.

Comment: Does ```NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear``` repeat the notification every week?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear` is just a const. If you set `repeatInterval` of the `UILocalNotification` instance to this const and then schedule that notification, and considering all other needed setup for local notifications is successful, then the notification will be repeated once a week after its initial `fireDate`.

Comment: @zubko Awesome thanks. Yeah I knew it was a const (or enum), but looking on the developer documentation, all I could find was a 2 line description, which wasn't very helpful to be honest.