# How to replace deprecated NSWeekCalendarUnit in context of UILocalNotification?

Tags: ios, date, ios7, uilocalnotification

In iOS 7.0 the `NSWeekCalendarUnit` has been deprecated. The documentation says it has to be replaced:

> Use NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth or NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear, depending
>   on which you mean

I am using `NSWeekCalendarUnit` for **weekly reminders**, which one do I have to pick to get the same meaning? I dont understand the difference between `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth` and `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear`.

Someone has asked the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22341048/92153) here on SO, without an convincing answer.

It quite confusing.  `Next week` is in my understanding atomic.  Today is `Sun 30 March 2014`. Hence `Next week` will always be `Sun 6 March 2014`. How could that change from a month or year perspective?

Comment: Normally, NSCalendarUniwWeekOfMonth will return 1 for the first week of the month, whatever is the value of month, whereas NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear will return differents values (there are around 52 weeks in a year, against 4/5 in a month).

Comment: Thanks and what does that mean in context of UILocalNotification? :)

Comment: I'd suggest to use NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear to get a reminder each year, because I think that using NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth will for only for the current month (value going to 1 to 4). To debug, add a week to a date, iterate seeing theses two values of NSDateComponents.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you were using NSWeekCalendarUnit to trigger a weekly reminder, replace it with NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear:

```
if (days == 7) localNotif.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;        // deprecated
if (days == 7) localNotif.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear;
```

You should find your weekly notification still works correctly.

Apple's documentation should be updated to provide guidance on the appropriate replacement.