# kCFCalendarUnitWeek deprecated in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I had a local notification and I set repeatInterval like this

```
notification.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitWeek;
```

but now `kCFCalendarUnitWeek` is deprecated.

What can I use instead of this constant.

Thanks a lot..

Comment: Do you mean deliveryRepeatInterval?

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear` with the `repeatInterval` of your `UILocalNotification`. If you had used the `NSWeekCalendarUnit`, it would have informed you to use either `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear` or `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth`, and in this case you want to use the former.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25555560/1271826.