# Set notification called everyweek

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I want to set notification to repeat every week. How to do that, I don't see `NSCalendarUnit.Week`, only see `NSCalendarUnit.Day`, and I can't set `NSCalendarUnit.Day * 7`. So, how to do this? Does `notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfMonth` work?

```
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.
```

Answer (score 2):

How about `WeekOfMonth` or `WeekOfYear`? They have two different implementations so be sure to read the documentation around both. Or look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22341336/112862) post.